# Update query gets rolled back

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

So I have something like this:

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate :check_credit
  belongs_to :user

  private

  def check_credit
    check = HTTParty.get(CREDIT_URL, query: {account_id: id})

    if !check.eligible
      user.update_attributes(:xx => xx)
      errors.add(:base, "Sorry, you are not eligible")
    end
  end
end
```

When I watch the log, the `user.update_attributes(:xx => xx)` seems to fire up then roll back, I figured it's because I add an error, but I'm not sure why it's an issue because that update is not related to the validation and should execute even if there is a validation error.

Any way to get around this?

Comment: Is this your actual code? it appears you're missing an else clause, or at least an end to the if clause

Comment: I know that `update_attributes` pass through the validations, but `update_attribute` doesn't.

Comment: `update_attributes` triggers validation, and you call it inside a validation... that seems strange to me, validation should not update the model. Use `before_validation` or `before_save` instead, or maybe just replace `user.update_attributes(:xx => xx)` by `user.xx = xx`.

Comment: @Baldrick `user.xx = xx` gets rolled back too.

Answer (score 0):

Might it be that the user object is invalid? In case you have errors in an object, then Active record won't update the database:

From the [documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html):

> If any validations fail, the object will be marked as invalid and
>   Active Record will not perform the INSERT or UPDATE operation